# save user input data and make them accessible to the user

Tags: android

should i use SQ.lite(or are there other ways) to make an app which allows to input text and numbers and saves those data and that data should be able to accessible to the user anytime they want(permanent data storage until user decides to delete)??

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: Please look into the following documentation. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: Do you need user's data on other device,too?

Answer (score 0):

I you want to store table structures, you should use SQLite. If your data is a relatively small collection of key-value pairs, SharedPreferences is more efficient.

According to documentation,

> A SharedPreferences object points to a file containing key-value pairs and provides simple methods to read and write them. Each SharedPreferences file is managed by the framework and can be private or shared.

Answer (score 0):

- Use Shared Preferences for primitive data.
- Use internal device storage for private data.
- Use external storage for large data sets that are not private.
- Use SQLite databases for structured storage.

Refer to this [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)